# Wine and Cyrillic Fonts

Tags: fonts, wine, cyrillic

Run Wine under Linux Mint 17.2. Cyrillic names of programs, menu items names, text files - all are unreadable.

Some exceptions do exist. For example, I can see Cyrillic text in CoDeSys IDE, but all my keyboard input is "????" on a screen. And Cyrillic program names are still weird...

Searched in Russian sites, but all receipts are of such kind: "I've tried so and so and this helped". Some of advice I managed to use but to no avail.

One example. I added files ru and ua in /var/lib/locales/supported.d/ and inserted

uk_UA.CP1251 CP1251

uk_UA.KOI8-R KOI8-R

ru_RU.CP1251 CP1251

ru_RU.KOI8-R KOI8-R

in file local. Then executed locale-gen and rebooted.

Another way is to edit Wine registry. I changed Codepages=1252,437 to 1251,866 - but this change gave no result. More of it, the changes are not remembered - reentering regedit shows old Codepages.

And yes, I've added old Windows XP ttf fonts - it was the very 1-st attempt on the problem.

Now I'm at a loss. Any help appreciated, but most of all - to understand the way Wine handles fonts. If it is possible for a dummy.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For some applications it's important to have proper ansi codepage set, I know for sure that classic Delphi 5/6/7 applications suffer from this. All you need is to run them with LANG set accordingly. Like this:

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 wine program.exe
```

Of course you need to have this locale present on your system, normally you don't need to reboot after enabling new locale data.

Comment: bunglehead, it helps! At least my CODESYS shows and accepts Cyrillic. And 2 programs else show good results (one of them doesn't show russian words in menu bar - let it be). I cannot check all in details just now - but thanks! Though it seems I had tried this way earlier... Don't remember.

Comment: I would like to add that wine deliberately ignores `LANG` on macOS, one has to set `LC_ALL` there.

Comment: @kirelagin Thanks a lot! I'm on Manjaro but my wine also ignored LANG, but setting LC_ALL helped.

Answer (score 10):

In some cases (for example if you need to type in **Solo** app) you might need to:

1. reconfigure your locales

   `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales && sudo update-locale`
   In `locales to be generated` choose (using space key) **ru_RU.CP1251 CP1251**

   ---
2. Run it using

   LC_ALL="ru_RU.CP1251" wine "/home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Solo/Solo.exe"

---

P.S. install corefonts if you've not done it yet

```
winetricks corefonts
```